# Отладка и тестирование программного модуля

Tags: c++, qt, тестирование, отладка, юнит-тесты

Здравствуйте!

Разрабатываю-создаю ПМ в QT, нужно провести его отладку, тестирование.
Вопрос, что нужно писать в документации по отладке, тестированию? Отладка и тестирование это не почти одно и тоже?
Отладка, я так понял, это исправление разного рода ошибок через отладчик, а тестирование?  Cunit тесты какие-нибудь? Вообще тестирование это разве не часть отладки??? Тестирование на самом деле нужно выделять в особый раздел? Подскажите способы тестирования приложения, мне научрук толкал про черные и белые ящики что-то, но я ума не приложу каким боком мне их применить в реальной программе.(  Вот еще, а в отладке что обычно пишут? Отлаживал мол стандартным отладчиком, всё хорошо мол, 500 ворнингов)???

Comment: отлаживать можно и без отладчика (да, ужас) - с помощью файлов с логами.

тестирование - это, грубо говоря, сверка работы Вашей программы с ТЗ. Или просто человек берет и пытается вызывать основные функции (там логин какой-нибудь, создание нового элемента) и проверяет, что оно работает как ожидается.

Comment: Ссылка из ответа: http://osherove.com/videos/2009/8/25/unit-testing-best-practices.html

Comment: Еще ссылка: http://www.slideshare.net/amritayan/test-driven-development-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Отладка и тестирование - две совершенно разные вещи.
**Отладка** - это процесс устранения ошибок в коде Вашей программы. Как уже упомянули выше, производиться она может как при помощи каких-то инструментов (отладчика, профайлера), так и путем вывода сообщений на консоль или в лог-файл, или просто путем наблюдений за поведением программы после запуска и фиксированием того факта, что некая часть работает отлично от Ваших ожиданий.
**Тестирование** - это уже следующий этап в жизни Вашей программы, - исследование поведения программы в каких-то заданных условиях, а так же в нештатных ситуациях, выяснение соответствия поведения программы тому, которое описано в ТЗ и пользовательской документации. Помимо поиска ошибок, тестирование может преследовать цель определить надежность, быстродействие, реакцию на высокие нагрузки, или какие-то особенности работы программы, а так же другие ее характеристики, которыми, к примеру, можно похвастаться на презентации данного программного продукта.

**В разделе об отладке** ПО можно указать, какие инструменты Вы использовали для того, чтобы выявить ошибки и настроить работу своей программы. Например, если Вы пишите сетевой сервер, Вы можете указать, что использовали *GDB* для устранения ошибок, а так же *Valgrind* для поиска утечек памяти, и утилиту *Iperf* для проверки скорости обработки запросов.

**В разделе о тестированиии** Вы должны описать, каким образом человеку, который не принимал участие в разработке программы, можно убедиться в том, что программа работоспособна, и ее поведение соответсвует тому, что отражено в ТУ и документации пользователя. Должна быть отражена предполагаемая методика тестирования и инструменты, которыми целесообразно пользоваться при проведении тестирования. Применительно к вышеописанному примеру с сетевым сервером, должен быть описан порядок действий для того, чтобы послать на сервер тот или иной запрос (например, какие действия нужно предпринять человеку, тестирующему Вашу программу, чтобы сервер переслал файл из базы данных?). В качестве вспомогательных инструментов тестирования в данном  случае могли бы выступить, например, *Wireshark* и *tcpdump*, или какие-нибудь тестовые скрипты, позволяющие отправлять запросы на Ваш сервер.

Важно понимать, что не все инструменты можно четко отнести только к группе отладочных или тестовых. Например, утилитой *Iperf* можете пользоваться как Вы в процессе отладки, так и человек, который будет ее тестировать. Однако тестирование подразумевает, что о внутреннем устройстве тестируемой программы ничего не известно, и поэтому отладчик или профайлер к инструментам тестирования не относятся.